# What does Cordova refer to in this sentence?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage

Reading Cloud Atlas, and ran into the following sentence:

> My new room is big enough for badminton doubles...centuries-old
>   Cordova peels off the walls like dragons’ scales...

What’s Cordova refer to above? It sounds like wallpaper, and there appears to be a library (programming library) named dealing with Cordova wallpaper, but otherwise google only returned results for wallpapering services in locations called Cordova.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cordoba leather](http://www.tassin-cuir.com/en/site/cordoue) is a type of [painted and gilded leather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuir_de_Cordoue) that can be used as a wall covering.

Comment: This answer is obviously correct, and yet it raises a deep mystery—namely, why would Chrysler name an automobile model "Cordoba" and then make a selling point of its seats being available in "[fine Corinthian leather](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgZLdhWjTSI)"?